# Tab switching in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

i have Tab host which is shown below,

```
 private TabHost myTabHost;

......    

    setContentView(R.layout.vidtab);


    Intent intent=getIntent(); 


    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, RecordActivityGroup.class);
    myTabHost = (TabHost)this.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    myTabHost.setup();
    TabSpec rectab = myTabHost.newTabSpec("Record");
    rectab.setIndicator("Record",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.irecord));
    rectab.setContent(intent);

    myTabHost.addTab(rectab);
   intent = new Intent().setClass(this, sharingProject.class);

    TabSpec setting = myTabHost.newTabSpec("Hint");
    setting.setIndicator("Hint",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.isettings));
    setting.setContent(intent);

    myTabHost.addTab(setting);
```

in that record Activity group i have following code,

RecordActivityGroup extends TabGroupActivity{

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    startChildActivity("RecordingActivity", new Intent(this,Record.class));



}
```

and Record.class is an activity which contain one button, i need to switch to second tab while clicking button in Record class, how to do that? i any one know that please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an method in your main class like following

```
public void switchToTab(int tabid){
            myTabHost.setCurrentTab(tabid);
}
```

And now in Record class on your Button click call this

```
        YourStartCalss parentActivity;
        parentActivity= (YourStartCalss) this.getParent();
        parentActivity.switchToTab(yourtabid);
```

Comment: in which class i have to declare the method switchToTab(), whether in tabhost or in recordActivitygroup

Comment: In the class where you have  `private TabHost myTabHost;`

Comment: i created the method as you say in Tabhost class , then i called that method , it throws class cast exception.

Comment: Thanks tanmay, i made a small mistake sorry for that ,its working know.